# facing button set using bootstrap

Tags: html

I am trying to set a redigera button after the avsluta button

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button class="form-control" style="width:80px;height:50px;" type="button">Avsluta</button>
        <button class="form-control" style="width:90px; height:50px;" type="button">Redigera</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

why my redigera button not set after the avsluta button

what I am trying

first I give the space 4 and then 4 and then 4 but avsluta button is set the below line

again I give the space 4 and then 3 and then 2 but avsluta button is set the below line

but not work

I am making a mistake partition of bootstrap or too many space I give

Reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `btn` class for the button. By default all html elements are `block` elements. This will take a complete row for the display of the element. adding `btn` class will make the button an `inline-block` element. This will allow multiple elements in the same line.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button class="form-control btn btn-primary" style="width:80px;height:50px;" type="button">Avsluta</button>
    <button class="form-control btn btn-primary" style="width:90px; height:50px;" type="button">Redigera</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "d-flex flex-row" to the div containing the buttons.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex flex-row">       
            <button class="form-control" style="width:80px;height:50px;" type="button">Avsluta</button>
            <button class="form-control" style="width:90px; height:50px;" type="button">Redigera</button>
    </div>
</div>
```